# Generate Combination using multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to generate combination using multi array, this is possible if i have fixed array set but in case of multi array `foreach` is not helpful, for example :

```
$first_array = [1,2,3];

$second_array = [1];
```

I want the output like this, total **3 combinations** :

```
First Combination : 11
Second Combination : 21
Third Combination : 31
```

If i have another array value in second array like following :

```
$second_array = [1,2];
```

Then output will be like this, total **6 combinations** :

```
// My Solution
$i = 1;
foreach ($first_array as $o) {
 foreach ($second_array as $s) {
  echo $i . ' : ' . $o . $s;
  echo "<br/>";
  $i++;
 }
}

1 : 11
2 : 12
3 : 21
4 : 22
5 : 31
6 : 32
```

I can solve this by using `foreach` but if i have multi array for example, if also have third array :

```
$third_array = [1,2,3];
```

Then output will be like this, total **18 combinations** :

```
// My Solution
$i = 1;
foreach ($first_array as $o) {
 foreach ($second_array as $s) {
  foreach ($third_array as $t) {
   echo $i . ' : ' . $o . $s . $t;
   echo "<br/>";
   $i++;
  }
 }
}

1 : 111
2 : 112
3 : 113
4 : 121
5 : 122
6 : 123
7 : 211
8 : 212
9 : 213
10 : 221
11 : 222
12 : 223
13 : 311
14 : 312
15 : 313
16 : 321
17 : 322
18 : 323
```

Is there any easiest solution to achieve this without multi `foreach`?
Because if have another array sets like following :

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Why is `foreach` not helpful? Seems like a fine solution to me. How else would you expect all to combinations to match?

Comment: I don't know how much array set i have, so that `foreach` not helpful, in my case if i have 6 array set then i need to add 6 `foreach` or is there any another way

Comment: Even if you were to find some fancy other solution, using array functions for instance, in the end they will all have to walk all the arrays and combine them, which is equivalent to multiple foreach loops. The only way to save processing steps is to remember intermediate results. I also think you should at least give us a working foreach example, with the amount of arrays you need, so we've got something to work on.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh How can you not know how many arrays you will have? Help us understand the bigger picture, so we can think about a different approach

Comment: your question is confusing us please edit and elaborate briefly ...son't say that you can do that just explain what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to add `foreach` for every single level. Three foreaches are fine for any number of components

```
function array_permute($arrays) {
    $set = array_shift($arrays);
    foreach($arrays as $sub) {
        $newSet = [];
        foreach($set as $prefix) {
            foreach($sub as $suffix){
                $newSet[] = $prefix.$suffix;
            }
        }
        $set = $newSet;
    }
    return $set;
}
```

Usage

```
print_r(array_permute([
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2],
    [1,2,3]
]));
```

Will result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111
    [1] => 112
    [2] => 113
    [3] => 121
    [4] => 122
    [5] => 123
    [6] => 211
    [7] => 212
    [8] => 213
    [9] => 221
    [10] => 222
    [11] => 223
    [12] => 311
    [13] => 312
    [14] => 313
    [15] => 321
    [16] => 322
    [17] => 323
)
```

Usage with more components

```
print_r(array_permute([
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6]
]));
```